# Scan Running Processes for Malware

Tags: anti-virus, avast

I am running the latest free version of Avast. I have, what I think is a virus, on a computer. It is running completely fine and Avast shows no kind of warnings, even with the Real-Time shield on.

How can I scan running processes to check whether it is malicious in Avast?

Comment: Is Avast fully updated? What's the name of the process? What makes you think it's a virus?

Comment: It could be a new virus, it still might not have been added to the virus database.

Comment: I have the latest updates for Avast, including the client and virus definitions.

Comment: @Marv You need to edit your question to actually ASK a question.

Comment: @Moab I thought the question was implied in the title. Nevertheless, I have edited the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you think you have a virus, it is better you scan with another software, I suggest:
Kaspersky Virus Removal Tool:
http://www.kaspersky.com/antivirus-removal-tool?form=1

Give it a try and see if you are infected.